# Why doesn't a WIX major upgrade update all of my files?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, wix

I've just taken over a complicated Visual Studio/WiX project (I've never used WiX) and all of a sudden upgrades no longer include all of the files.

We don't version every .dll so we need to do every upgrade as a Major Upgrade. (I know this isn't usually a good idea, but this is for an appliance that only gets upgraded by a script on a USB drive). I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138731/wix-major-upgrade-not-installing-all-files) article and made the following changes:

1. I changed the Product Id from a Guid to an '*'  in the Product.wxs file
2. I added `<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallFinalize" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."/>` to the Product.wxs file (I've also tried Schedule=afterInstallExecute) with no luck.
3. I added the following block of code to the Product.wxs file:

   ```
   <Upgrade Id='291EF866-D9B7-4103-B006-F11E50EEDC7B'> <UpgradeVersion 
   OnlyDetect='no' Property='PREVIOUSFOUND' Minimum='1.0.0' 
   IncludeMinimum='yes' Maximum='99.0.0' IncludeMaximum='no' />
   </Upgrade>
   ```

So when I started this process some of the .dlls were updating and others weren't. Now most update, but not all. Here's a sample line from the log for one of the files that's not updating:

```
 MSI (s) (34:AC) [16:56:06:306]: Component: cmp9EE90E3731EB7F54B1D4B6D421BF1286; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Local
```

And here's the second line that refers to that file:

```
MSI (s) (34:98) [16:56:08:583]: Component: cmp9EE90E3731EB7F54B1D4B6D421BF1286; Installed: Local;   Request: Absent;   Action: Null
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Schedule to afterInstallInitialize in the MajorUpgrade 
 element.

```
 Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
```

And remove the Upgrade element.

You can check the specifics in [this tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html).

And I suggest you to read about the Schedule attribute from [Here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html).

Comment: I got it to work by adding:     <Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" />. Thanks though - I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Nope - that doesn't work. I'm going back to my original fix (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work with an obscure property called REINSTALLMODE and setting it's Value to amus. Thanks Hannes for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603333/wix-major-upgrade-replace-files-regardless-of-newer-file-version) post!!

Here's the solution:

```
<Property Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" />

<Upgrade Id='291EF866-D9B7-4103-B006-F11E50EEDC7B'>
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='no' Property='PREVIOUSFOUND'
      Minimum='1.0.0' IncludeMinimum='yes'
      Maximum='99.0.0' IncludeMaximum='no' />
</Upgrade>
```