# MajorUpgrade removes old version, but doesn't install the new version unless the MSI is run a second time

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have two MSIs that are identical except for their ProductIds and Versions. I'm testing the MajorUpgrade pathway [to make sure it's seamless for end users](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html).

The MSI with the higher version shuts down the Windows service, and removes all the artifacts, but then fails at installing the "new" binaries with a 1603 error. *In fact, it looks like it's executing the uninstall, including file and registry cleanup, but then failing to execute the installation.*

If I run the higher versioned MSI again, the install works just fine: files and directories are created, and the Windows service is started, as well as the executable I've set to run after installation completes.

I generated a detailed log (snippets below), but fixing what appears to be the problem (the files aren't copied to the right places) isn't obvious.

Wix code:

```
<Product Id="*"
    Name="product name"
    Language="1033"
    Version="1.2.0"
    Manufacturer="Company Name"
    UpgradeCode="stable-upgrade-guid">

<!-- snip -->

<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#TheProgram.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
                  BinaryKey="WixCA"
                  DllEntry="WixShellExec"
                  Impersonate="yes" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CheckForRunningProcesses_CA" After="InstallValidate" />
      <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I generated the log below with `msiexec /i "product.msi" /l*v "upgrade.log"`. This seems to be the relevant bit:

```
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:905]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:905]: Note: 1: 1321 2: C:\Config.Msi\ 3: 5 
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:905]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:905]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 2911 
DEBUG: Error 2911:  Could not remove the folder C:\Config.Msi\.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2911. The arguments are: C:\Config.Msi\, , 
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:908]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:908]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 0, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 14, szDescription: "".
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:909]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:909]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:911]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 14:30:58: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:912]: Doing action: LaunchApplication
MSI (s) (70:B0) [14:30:58:912]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 14:30:58: LaunchApplication. 
Action start 14:30:58: LaunchApplication.
MSI (s) (70:58) [14:30:58:915]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI12D1.tmp, Entrypoint: WixShellExec
WixShellExec:  Error 0x80070002: ShellExec failed with return code 2.
WixShellExec:  Error 0x80070002: failed to launch target
CustomAction LaunchApplication returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 14:30:58: LaunchApplication. Return value 3.
Action ended 14:30:58: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

- I believe ShellExec return code 2 means "file not found". (Indeed, the program files directory isn't present.)
- I'm not sure what LaunchApplication having a return value of 3 means. I would guess "file not found".

Any idea why the MajorUpgrade removes the old version, but doesn't install the new version, but on a subsequent run, it does?

Comment: It's not _exactly_ a duplicate. Similar symptom, completely different log files. The solution was the same, but the root problem was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally I discover the answer moments after asking the question. The clue was [in this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138731/wix-major-upgrade-not-installing-all-files), which somehow I hadn't seen...

> To work around the problem, you need to move your
>   RemoveExistingProducts action later. If you're using the MajorUpgrade
>   element then `Schedule='afterInstallExecute'` or
>   `Schedule='afterInstallFinalize'` should do the trick. You'll need to be
>   more careful with the Component Rules.

Changing the `MajorUpdate`'s schedule to `afterInstallExecute` was the fix:

```
<MajorUpgrade
      DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit."
      Schedule="afterInstallExecute" />
```

Not at all obvious.